# Rails 3 validations error with two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am still learning the ropes in ruby on rails and this question might be simple, but its bugging me for sometime now
Environment: rails 3.2, ruby 1.9 on ubuntu
I am building a small reviews app to learn ruby on rails.e
I have a webpage reviews/new.erb where I save the new reviews.It will have the movie name displayed at the top.

reviews/new.erb looks like this

```
<h3><%= @movie.name %></h3>
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @review %>
<%= f.hidden_field :movie_id %>
<%= f.label :rating, "Rate the movie" %>
<%= f.select :rating,['1','2','3','4'] %>
<%= f.label :review, "Your 140 character review" %>
<%= f.text_area :review %>
<%= f.submit "Fire", :disable_with => 'Submitting...' %>
<% end %>
```

My controller methods for new and create are

```
def new
    @movie=Movie.find(params[:movie])
    @review=Review.new
end

def create
 @user=current_user
 @review=Review.create params[:review]
 @review.user_id=@user.id
 @review.movie_id=params[:movie_id]
 @movie=Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
 if @review.save
   flash[:notice] = 'Movie was successfully created.'
   redirect_to :controller => "movies",:action => "show",:id => @review.movie_id
 else
   redirect_to :action => "new", :movie => @movie
 end  
end
```

When I am trying to display a validation error message in the new.erb,I am getting this error

```
Couldn't find Movie without an ID

Rails.root: /home/Development/ohmyroots
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

My other form to add movies which does not have mixed content is working fine.
Suggestions on fixing this would be appreciate.Thanks.

I am using dynamic form gem for displaying validations in views

UPDATE: My new create method

```
def create
@review=Review.create(params[:review])
@user=current_user
@review.user_id=@user.id
@review.movie_id=params[:movie_id]
@review.rating=params[:rating]
@review.review=params[:review]
if @review.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Movie was successfully created.'
  redirect_to :controller => "movies",:action => "show",:id => @review.movie_id
else
  @movie=Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  render :action => "new",:movie => @movie
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviews/new.erb is currently a form that isn't passing the movie's ID to the create action. That is why you're getting an error that it can't find a movie without an ID.

Try making this change to the hidden field tag:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, :value => @movie.id %>
```

Comment: Thanks that was quite fast.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, the thing is whatever i try I am unable to send the movie id to the else block it always says its unable to find it @review=Review.new({:movie_id => @movie.id}) or <%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, :value => @movie.id %>

Answer (score 0):

You have added the form for the Review object but while initializing the object, all the attributes for the object is blank so as movie_id. So you are getting this error, so to fix it, we can initialize the object while creation. Just add the following codes to the new action of your controller.

```
def new
    @movie=Movie.find_by_id(params[:movie])
    @review=Review.new({:movie_id => @movie.id})
end
```

And in the view page,

```
<%= f.hidden_field :movie_id %>
```

Hope, it will work for you :)

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, the thing is whatever i try I am unable to send the movie id to the else block it always says its unable to find it  @review=Review.new({:movie_id => @movie.id}) or <%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, :value => @movie.id %>

Comment: Hi rails4sandeep, if you are initializing the @review model by adding movie_id to it, then you don't have to explicit passing the value in the html, you can simply write <%= f.hidden_field :movie_id %> .

Comment: And please check while you fetching the @movie, does it returns nil. means just check whether @movie.blank? returns true or false.